Hotspot keeps getting disconected
I use iPhone hotspot connecting my laptop as I do not have wifi.  The hotspot has been problematic. it keeps getting disconnected, especially when laptop goes to sleep/screen turn off
I found a article on this site, which says that

Auto lock needs to be set to never, and it fixed the issue.

But that setting is already configured, yet it disconnects frequently.
Recently when I try to connect my MacBook & windows laptop with the hotspot, I see a dialog box, with title of 'join iPhone' and it fails to loads. so I cross it out.
I don't know what is going on but it is very fustrating
My phone is iPhone 14 Pro Max.
Edit: Today I tried with samsung hotspot and I saw the same dialog box and same message as in screenshot


Which version of iOS are you running? Do you connect via Bluetooth or Wifi? Does it happen with all devices connecting to that phone, or only with some? Can you add a link to the post you found?

I didn't know we can use hotspot using bluetooth. I am using it wifi, I am using version 17.5.1, I got 2 laptops and same have same issue, the hotspot seem to turn off from my mobile from time to time @nohillside I have also attached what pop up I see when it is connected

Thanks. This is from a browser or similar. What is the connection status in Control Center at such moments? And is the iPhone still showing the blue Hotspot indicator?

@nohillside personal hotspot is currently green. When it is disconnected, the icon isn't lit up like it should to tell it is off

Ah, the question was rather: When you get the error message in the screenshot, how does the hotspot status look like?

@nohillside it is the same as I mentioned above. Green icon and connected

Check that Low Data Mode (in Cellular settings) and Low Power Mode (in Battery settings) are both disabled on the phone

If the phone still shows an active hotspot, it might be an issue with the server you try to access. Do other sites work?

judging by that weird "join iPhone" dialog, it seems like your cellular provider is limiting something

@LincD. I checked and that is not the case.

When the hotspot drops out, is cellular Internet working on the phone itself?

@LincD. yes the internet is working fine. The hotspot drop itself, or when laptop goes to sleep or idle for a while. Mostly iPhone which is next to laptop and on charge mostly is turned off automatically

Can you reproduce this problem in different locations? If not, there may be an issue with RF interference at your workplace. You should test with a USB connection between the phone and the sharing device.

The dialog in your screenshot is usually seen when Safari fails to load a captive portal. Is that what you're doing? I don't think the hotspot is dropping out at all; you're just being kicked off the local network.

@LincD. The dialog box shows as soon as I join any hotspot, today it happened with samsung as well. Another thing I noticed that no website work in some cases., I have to log out and then when I log back in, it loads website, the dialog box still remain.

So you have two hotspots, from different manufacturers, and two clients, also from different manufacturers, and neither client works with either hotspot. This is neither a Mac problem nor an iPhone problem. Something in your environment is interfering with the Wi-Fi signal. To confirm, I suggest you test the connection somewhere else, if you haven't already done so.

@LincDavis I was out of city and tried same, but it was happening again and again. so environment rules out, I noticed something new, my macbook won't pick up iPhone hotspot even if it is very near

Then it's a hardware fault, such as a detached antenna. Go to an Apple Store for diagnosis.
